# UDP live webcam streaming with VLC on linux to iPhone

Tags: linux, ios, udp, video-streaming, vlc

I've searched on the web for something like this, but everything is about ´saving the file on ipod´ and some offtopic solutions and examples that i can't really use.

I want my linux laptop to stream the webcam media to my iPod (with my code) I am really lost on this.. I could use VLC to stream it in UDP from the laptop, but how would i get it and show on the iPod side? Should i use mpmovieplayer?

Note: I could send the frames in iplimage (from my linux code:blocks project) to the iPod, and for what i've searched on the web, there are methods to transform IplImage to UIImage on the iPod, but i don't know how to make it work :s

thks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you best bet would be to use ffmpeg. When you just want to stream videos that you have taken with your webcam you can just encode it correctly with ffmpeg and the iPhone will automagically do a progressive download, in most cases this will do.

Something like this :

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -acodec libfaac -ab 128kb -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1200kb -mbd 2 -flags +4mv -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -s 320x180 $1.mp4
```

when you however need real live streaming i would look at the following projects.

I played around with this project: http://www.ioncannon.net/projects/http-live-video-stream-segmenter-and-distributor/ but I remember it to be quite complex. It should however provide what you want.

Considering you are using a linux laptop, you might be interested in http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Streaming_to_iPod_touch_or_iPhone 
I think however it is missing the realtime component.

On the ipod side i think MPMoviePlayerViewController (ios 4.0) is the way to go, just implement the delegate methods and if the iPod can play it, this controller will handle everything.

I hope this helps, if you find an (easy) solution let us know ;-).